# How to run tests with FlutterMap widget?

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I have a test which has to load a screen which contains the FlutterMap widget. Unfortunately the test throws an exception because all http calls for the map tile images return a 400 response. I would have to mock a http client that responds with an example image as the body but couldn't find a way to do so. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please include some code of your current failing test and possibly the screen being tested to make it easier to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the `TileLayer`, it should be possible to specify a `tileProvider`. In this case, you should be able to use `NetworkTileProvider`, as is the default, but it is possible to pass in a custom `BaseClient`, if that fits your needs. For more information, see https://docs.fleaflet.dev/layers/tile-layer/tile-providers#network-tile-provider.